# Clean URL for custom content

Tags: uri

I have a custom content type movie. Now, when I visit any of the movie content, the url is like:

```
mysite/?q=node/someNumber
```

I want that every movie content will have url like

```
mysite/movie/somenumber
```

or,

```
mysite/?q=book/someNumber
```

How to do this?

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Do you have clean URLs enabled?  You shouldn't need to enable a special kind of clean URL just for custom content.

Answer (score 6):

Enable Clean URL + get [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, which allows to define custom URL patterns for every type of content

If the Clean URL test fails, the web-server is not configured to support this feature. You need to configure the web-server to support Clean URL.

With Apache HTTPD as web-server, you have to enable `mod_rewrite` and configure the necessary rewrite rules. The rewrite rules can be found in the `.htaccess` file that comes with Drupal. Usually, theses rules are applied automatically, when `mod_rewrite` is enabled, but in some cases, the `AllowOverride` directive is too restrictive to allow this.

See [Clean URLs](http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls) in the Drupal Installation Guide for a more thorough introduction on how to get Clean URLs working in Drupal.

Comment: i cant enable the clean URL , the test fails

Comment: What kind of test? where are you enabling the clean URLs? can you paste the URL? (starting with /admin/...)

Comment: mysite.com/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin/config/search/clean-urls

Comment: OK, I just wanted to know if we are talking about same admin section. Now, what was it that you tried to do on that page and what was the symptom?

Comment: When selecting Clean URL option , it asks to "run the Clean URL test", but the test fails

Comment: At my setup, the form has just a single checkbox 'Enable clean URLs' (Use URLs like example.com/user instead of example.com/?q=user.) Are you sure you don't have a module enabled that hooks up to the form and modifies it? It happened to me during extensive learning that I installed tons of modules before I got a simple solution... Worth checking,

Comment: If the test fails this is a web server configuration issue. Read the documentation in the installation guide carefully and make sure you have have your server correctly set up before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Clean URL, then install and enable the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, which allows to define custom URL patterns for custom content.

If the "Clean URL test" fails, you need to enable Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

Usually, it is suffiscient to put this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ $1
```

If the above two line don't fix the problem, your web server is not set up to allow rewrite rules. In that case, it is necessary to enable an extension to the Apache web-server known as `mod_rewrite`. You do this with the following shell command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then navigate to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and edit the file named `default`. Locate the following block of text:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

And change the `AllowOverride` directive to:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
</Directory>
```

When done, restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

(The above example is assuming you're running a standard Apache configuration on Ubuntu ver. 12. YMMV, and you may have to dig out the documentation for your system to see how to do something similar.)